# Unwanted Shadow in PNG Transparent Area While Hover

Tags: html, css

I'm using a png image as a button with a link.  Something like this:

```
<p><a href="https://www.blabla.com/"><img src="/image.png" width="50" height="50" border="0"></a></p>
```

I do NOT want any effects on the image button.  But when I hover over the png image I'm getting what appears to be a ghost shadow in a portion of the transparent area of the png.

I've seen this before, and I know there is a way to solve it, but I can't find anything that works after much searching.

Comment: how this question is constructive?

Comment: it's probably caused by browser's user agent styles, but an example would be helpful

Comment: can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle/snippet? its hard to help you if we have no idea what you are talking about...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the JSFiddle suggestion.  I solved it while posting it there.

The problem appears specific to:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

I solved by adding the following CSS class:

```css
.nohov a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```